# Links in Codeigniter are not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I hope everyone will be doing good.
I am stuck in a serious issue since morning that all the links in my **CodeIgniter** project have stopped working. Till last night it was working fine. But now it's not working. **Url Helper** is imported.
Any sort of help would be appreciated.

```
<h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="<?php echo base_url('template'); ?>">Hotels Social Portal</a></h1>
<nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
<ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
<li><a class="" href="<?php echo base_url('template'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('hotels'); ?>" class="">Hotel<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Your showing ip in your url make sure you have set your base url in config.php as required to do so in CI3 versions and up

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';` Make sure your filenames and class names have **first letter upper case only.**

Comment: What was changed since it worked? Do you have a copy from the time it worked, then compare it to current versio using a tool.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thank you for your feedback. But its exactly like this $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/finalyp/';

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek you might need a htaccess try with index.php `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/templates` or you also may need to configure routes

Comment: @Yunnosch the problem is i don't have a copy of it. But i don't exactly remember what did i change in the morning. As till yesterday it was working fine.

Comment: @wolfgang1983omg. its working now when i type the link like this http://localhost/finalyp/index.php/hotelProfile . But why .htaccess isn't working? Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek try some of these htaccess also read the read me https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @wolfgang1983 alright dear. Let me check it out. Would add my comment then.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 the problem was with the name of the project. It was supposed to be capital 'F' in the beginning of the project name but i mistakenly typed that as small 'f'. Now its working. Thank You for your time.

Comment: "But i don't exactly remember what did i change in the morning." You should start using GIT or SVN (git would be my proposal), check github or bitbucket. When you get to use it your life will become way easier.

Comment: @Tpojka though i am writing code since years but still i don't know what is the purpose of github or bitbucket? I have created account in github long time ago. could you please explain it to me?

Comment: It is complex subject for one comment, even for one answer. In a nutshell, SVC or source version control tracks your every changes to files and keeps relation between your local and online copies of project (online here is meaning cloud server of github/bitbucket). Start with [service'](https://git-scm.com/) site or google/youtube query for git basics.

Comment: @Tpojka wow. It seems quite interesting. I would try to learn its usage. May be a tutorial from YouTube!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Set your base url in config/config.php  file. as follow.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname';
```

Comment: I just go by the comment above the base url in config.php

Answer (score 1):

**Set base url in config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```